# spark 3.0.2: Spark analyzer is not invoking ResolveMissingReferences while reusing the same projection after caching

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Tried running the below code snippet in spark 3.0.2

val df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)

val df1 = df.select(col1, col2).filter(col2 > 10).cache()

df1.count

However when i tried the below code, could see its not leveraging the cached data.

df.select(col2).filter(col2 > 10).count .

My understanding is that ResolveMissingReferences analyser rule will add the missing attribute and  leverage the cached data.

Any advice is highly appreciated ?